# Something is blocking ads and I don't know what it is

Tags: rooting, root-access, ads

I am not complaining, it's awesome, but strange. I have a rooted Samsung a5, sm a500h, android 6.1.

Few weeks ago I installed adaway, and removed it because it couldn't block youtube ads.

And now the vast majority of apps don't display ads anymore, with the exception of musixmatch and youtube. I browse webpages using chrome, i see no ads on any website, including forbes.com and it let me in without complaining about an ad blocker, on tumblr, the ad space says "couldn't connect  to server x"

I did clean my device multiple times, using the likes of clean master, I did restart it multiple times. Is it possible that adaway did all that?

Comment: I'm happy but a bit sad, I like to help fellow dev earn some money, I just hate youtube ads thats all coz they waste my time, it's like i have to watch 2 videos instead of 1

Comment: Lynob, sounds like the host file didn't reset. It's fixable, don't worry. I'll write it as an answer

Comment: Please see this new article 2017/02/10 [10 most useless apps and games for Android](http://www.androidauthority.com/most-useless-apps-android-749163). Most prominent, but specifically named in the list: Clean Master (along with quote-Booster apps, Anti-Virus apps, and Task Killers-unquote)

Comment: @wbogacz thanks for the article, good read, I removed clean master shortly after asking this question for the reasons mentioned in that article, it became huge, it became junk, rather than junk cleaner

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Somebody gone borked up their hosts file

Luckily, it's an easy fix. Your going to need root, and a root file manager (Like ES file explorer)

In your file explorer, go to /system/etc, and look for a file called 'hosts'. Open it, and remove **EVERYTHING except the top line** to disable the AD blocking. If you want to, of course

**But why?**

AdAway and similar apps use root auth to write to the hosts file the locations of ads. This then blocks them due to what said file does (it's a blacklist, essentially)